# jQuery and mobile Panel navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, intel-xdk

I have an HTML5 Mobile App I am building.  I am utilizing panels as pages in the following manner:

`<div class="upage panel" id="account_page" data-header="af-header-4" data-footer="none">`

I also have a login page that looks like the following:

```
<div class="upage panel" id="login_page" data-header="af-header-1" data-footer="none">
    <div class="upage-outer">
        <header class="container-group inner-element uib_w_5" data-uib="app_framework/header" data-ver="1" id="af-header-1">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left with-back"><a class="button" id="backButton" href="#mainpage">Back</a>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </header>
        <div id="login_pagesub" class="upage-content ">
            <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_6 row-height-6" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                <div class="col uib_col_8 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                        <div class="widget uib_w_17 d-margins login_status_lbl" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0" id="login_status_lbl">
                            <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
                            <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
                            <div>
                                <p>Please login to view your account.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_7 row-height-7" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                <div class="col uib_col_9 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                        <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_13 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="1">
                            <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Username" type="text" id="l_username" name="l_username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_14 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="1">
                            <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Password" type="text" id="l_password" name="l_password">
                        </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_8 row-height-8" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                <div class="col uib_col_10 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                        <a class="button widget uib_w_15 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="login_btn" onclick="verifyInfo()">Login</a><a class="button widget uib_w_16 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="proceed_btn"
                        href="#account_page" data-transition="fade">Proceed</a>
                        <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /upage-outer -->
</div>
```

So when the user enters their username and password they click the login button which has an onClick method attached to call a jQuery function.

`<a class="button widget uib_w_15 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1" id="login_btn" onclick="verifyInfo()">Login</a>`

```
function verifyInfo(){
    var uName=document.getElementById("l_username").value;
    var pWord=document.getElementById("l_password").value;
    $.ajax(  
    {  
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/TestWebService/Verify.asmx/UserVerify',
        data: "{ \"username\":\""+uName+"\",\"password\":\""+pWord+"\"}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        //dataFilter: function(data){alert(data);},
        success: function(data) {
            var response = JSON.stringify(data.d);
            if(response == "true"){
                alert("true");
                $("#account_page").panel("open");

            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('output_u').innerHTML="The Username or Password is incorrect, please try again.";
            }
        },
        error: function(data){alert('Failed on '+data.d);}
    });
}
```

Based on this my assumption of how this should be working is that onClick of the login button, the username and password are sent to the webservice, a boolean is sent back which I use json.stringify to use in a comparison conditional statement.  If it was verified (true) the panel (page) #account_page should be opened.  However this does not happen instead I get the following error in the XDK console:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'panel'`

Any ideas on what I can do differently here to accomplish the desired functionality?

Thanks in advance for any and all responses.

**Edit: Added the account_page div for better visibility**

```
<div class="upage panel" id="account_page" data-header="af-header-4" data-footer="none">
        <div class="upage-outer">
            <header class="container-group inner-element uib_w_8" data-uib="app_framework/header" data-ver="1" id="af-header-4">
                <h1>Account</h1>
                <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-cente  red"></div>
                <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left with-back"><a class="button" id="backButton" href="#mainpage">Back</a>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
            </header>
            <div id="account_pagesub" class="upage-content ">

                <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_9 row-height-9" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                    <div class="col uib_col_11 col-0_6-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                            <div class="widget uib_w_18 d-margins currbalance_label" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0" id="currbalance_label">
                                <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
                                <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>Current Balance:</p>
                                </div>
                            </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col uib_col_12 col-0_6-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                            <div class="widget uib_w_19 d-margins currbalance_datapoint" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0" id="currbalance_datapoint">
                                <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
                                <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <p>$38.99</p>
                                </div>
                            </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.location = $('#account_page').attr('href');` ?

Comment: I did at one point have a small work around using this method working, however; using the exact line you give here gives `404: Intel XDK can't find your app`

Comment: Where is `#account_page` panel in your markup above? I can only see `#login_page`. you want to change page or open a panel? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: account_page is added. I want to open a panel.

Comment: Pls post relevant markup, your current code is unclear. I can't tell whether the markup above is a page or a panel. panels should have `data-role="panel"` and pages `data-role="page"`.

Comment: Omar that is the code generated by the XDK builder there is nothing else to post.

Comment: Are you using jQuery-Mobile framework? and which version?

Comment: I have just started using XDK so as far as I am aware I am using the default app framework.

`<script type="application/javascript" src="app_framework/2.1/appframework.js"></script>`
`<script type="application/javascript" src="app_framework/2.1/appframework.ui.js" data-ver="1"></script>`
`<script src="cordova.js"></script>`
`<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_user_scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58710/discussion-between-omar-and-jdd).

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.panel`, try using `$.ui.loadContent("#account_page",false,false,"slide");`

[Docs here](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api.php#$_ui_loadContent)

also you shouldn't use 'localhost' as request URL, use your local IP address.

Comment: Currently, this answer is listed as low quality, and it looks like a comment. If you're sure about this, try also explain it a little bit.

Comment: whats to explain here? OP probably used wrong method so I suggested using other which might be actually ANSWER...

Comment: At least this looks better now. Thanks for including more information.

Comment: I gave this a shot todayjust to see if it might work.  I will continue to play with it.  The initial try yielded the following error.


`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadContent' of undefined index.html:137
(anonymous function) index.html:137
x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
v.handle jquery.min.js:5
x.event.trigger jquery.min.js:5
k jquery.min.js:6
r jquery.min.js:6`